# 'build' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: cmd, build

I'm trying to use [windivert](https://reqrypt.org/windivert.html) and go step by step in accordance with its [README](https://github.com/basil00/Divert) but can finished them and having trouble with **build** command, Error in below:

```
C:\Divert>wddk-build.bat
A subdirectory or file install\WDDK\ already exists.
'build' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Is it possible to guide me?

Comment: If not suit form for this question plz introduce place

Comment: Please create an issue on the windivert page. https://github.com/basil00/Divert/issues

Comment: Are you running this in a Visual-Studio command line? Did you first run wddk-build.bat successfully before running msvc-build.bat?

Comment: @mao 
all them not success
no, not running it . how can I do

Comment: @lit, doesn't this relate to environment variables? asking before flagging as duplicate

Comment: I cannot say that this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone come across this issue, the owner provides the answer here: https://github.com/basil00/Divert/issues/88#issuecomment-319060588

> No, that is VS2017. You need to build with WDK 7.1.0.